# Natibib entry without a year - How to insert dots?

Tags: natbib

In my literature directory I have got some sources, where I dont have a year, when it was published. This is why I use {o.J.} as my year. Compiling the whole thing, all my dots are erased. How to show them?

Here is an example entry:

```
@MISC{CMSDef,
  author = {{Gabler Wirtschaftslexikon}},
  title = {Content Management System (CMS)},
  year = {{o.J. }},
  note = {Zugriffen am 03.07.2013 {\"u}ber   \url{http://webpage.de/index.html}},
  owner = {Me},
  timestamp = {2013.05.04}
}
```

**EDIT1:**

How I insert my literature:

```
\bibliographystyle{chicago-new}
\bibliography{literatur/literatur}
```

The package I am using:

```
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Here is a link to the chicago-new.bst at pastebin: http://pastebin.com/7c8LxVwu

**EDIT 3**

Deleting purify did not work. I get lots of errors then. The console tells me, the second line is the critical one.

```
\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{{Blueray-Disc.de}}{{Blueray-Disc.de}}{J.
  }a}]{MP4Def}
```

This is how it looks, when purify is inside:

```
\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{{Blueray-Disc.de}}{{Blueray-Disc.de}}{oJ
  a}]{MP4Def}
```

Comment: I believe to have already seen something of this kind; can you please add a minimal document showing the bibliography packages you're using? Perhaps [Citations with no date](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63910/) helps, too.

Comment: Which bibliography style are you using?

Comment: The link by ereg is exactly what I am looking for, but I am using \bibliographystyle{chicago-new} for my literature.

Comment: The solution is probably the same, i.e., remove `purify$`, but to be sure we need to see your bibliography style. Google failed to find a `chicago-new.bst`.

Comment: http://ul.to/d7aa9qak Here you can download my bibliographystyle! Thanks so far!

Comment: Please use another upload method without any pop ups. Maybe http://pastebin.com/:

Comment: @tellob Removing `purify$` from the `calc.label` function seems to do in this case as well.

Comment: Did not help. :( I added another example from the generatet *.bbl, where the error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is exactly the same as in @egreg's answer in [Citations with no date, e.g. (Aristotle n.d.)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63910/): remove `purify$` from function `calc.label` in line 991 of your `chicago-new.bst`. This will work as expected as long as an author that has an entry without year does not occur again in a multicite, i.e., `\cite{CMSdef,CMSdef2}`. The reason is that `natbib` tries to compress years in entries from the same author, so

> Knuth (1975), Knuth (1976a), Knuth (1976b)

will actually come out as

> Knuth (1975, 1976a, b)

You can see this problem in the first citation in the sample output.
In this case, you might work around that by changing the way you cite, a few examples are given in the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{tellob.bib}
@MISC{CMSDef,
  author = {{Gabler Wirtschaftslexikon}},
  title = {Content Management System (CMS)},
  year = {o.J.},
  note = {Zugegriffen am 03.07.2013 {\"u}ber   \url{http://webpage.de/index.html}},
  owner = {Me},
  timestamp = {2013.05.04},
}
@MISC{CMSDef2,
  author = {{Gabler Wirtschaftslexikon}},
  title = {Content Management System (CMS) -- Directors Cut},
  year = {o.J.},
  note = {Zugegriffen am 03.07.2013 {\"u}ber   \url{http://webpage.de/index.html}},
  owner = {Me},
  timestamp = {2013.05.04},
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\citet{CMSDef,CMSDef2}

\citet{CMSDef}, \citet{CMSDef2}

\citet{CMSDef}, \citeyearpar{CMSDef2}

\citeauthor{CMSDef}, (\citeyear{CMSDef}, \citeyear{CMSDef2})

\bibliographystyle{chicago-new2}
\bibliography{tellob}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Regarding the problem in your third edit, check the braces in your bib file, they seem to be unbalanced.

<sub>I fixed the typo in Zu*ge*griffen</sub>

Comment: Ok that works now. The problem was, that I inserted it with braces like {o.J.}. Removing the braces and emoving purify solved the problem. Thank you!