# Marking something as undated in the bibliography

Tags: cross-referencing, books

I would like undated books to show up in the bibliography as undated, e.g. as something like:

> Oslo  kommune (undated). Nedre  poenggrense  for  inntak  til  Vg1  (videregående  trinn  1)  for  ungdommed opplæringsrett, skoleåret 2014/2015, 1. inntaksrunde. Online, accessed 07.05.15. url: http://www.vilbli.no/Data/Artikkelvedlegg/018630/2014_Nedre_poenggrense_1._inntak_Vg1.pdf.

Now, the `date` field is left empty, which then leaves that area empty in the output as well. What I want to do then, is make it something like the example above.

The MWE now looks like this:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ 
    style=authoryear-comp,
    backend=bibtex,
    dashed=true,
    natbib=true,
] {biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{bibliography = {References}}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

@book{Oslokommune2014,
    author = "{Oslo kommune}",
    title = "Nedre poenggrense for inntak til Vg1 (videregående trinn 1) for ungdom med opplæringsrett, skoleåret 2014/2015, 1. inntaksrunde",
    url = "http://www.vilbli.no/Data/Artikkelvedlegg/018630/2014_Nedre_poenggrense_1._inntak_Vg1.pdf",
    note = "Online, accessed 07.05.15",
    date = "",
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  For posting code, rather than including a `> ` before each code line, highlight the code and click the `{}` icon above the edit box.  This will indent your code 4 spaces in the edit box, which has the effect of rendering it as code by readers of your post.

Comment: What about [Citations with no date, e.g. (Aristotle n.d.)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63910/citations-with-no-date-e-g-aristotle-n-d) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, using `year = "undated"`instead of `date =" "`should do the trick. The reason, I think, why something like `date = "undated"` does not work is that the date field requires a properly formatted date expression while the year field does not.

```
@book{Oslokommune2014,
    author = "{Oslo kommune}",
    title = "Nedre poenggrense for inntak til Vg1 (videregående trinn 1) for ungdom med opplæringsrett, skoleåret 2014/2015, 1.
inntaksrunde",
    url = "http://www.vilbli.no/Data/Artikkelvedlegg/018630/2014_Nedre_poenggrense_1._inntak_Vg1.pdf",
note = "Online, accessed 07.05.15",
    year = "undated",
    }
```

This way, you can put arbitrary strings in the date field, like e.g. “to appear”, “in press”, or whatever you like.